# Bonding - 2 Devices failed

Tags: debian, bonding, proxmox

i have a Linux Server - Setup with Proxmox 2.3 (ISO-Installer). I  tried to update the Installation and so i got a Problem because I have to Links and must configure a bond. I have the Information from my Provider the Switch is configured fine to work with Bond-Mode "802.3ad" (without LACP - wich is not absolutely needed - they Say).

My /etc/network/interfaces looks so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address <server-ip>
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    network <network-ip>
    gateway <gateway-ip>
    bond_mode 802.3ad
    slaves eth0 eth1
```

The Problem is the Server doesn't get a "good"-Connection this mean if I make a ping on the IP / Hostname - this happend:

```
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=1583ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=26ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=26ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=1252ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=26ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Antwort von <ip>: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=58
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
```

So the Server is pingable, and not and is and not - this changes minutly. Can you say me what I could do?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the Problem - the Network goes down if i open the IPMI-Console of the Server - It's a Supermicro one. What "Lan Interface" Setting should I use to prevent this Problem or could I prevent it? (Options are: dedicated, shared, failover)

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated.  Note that unless you have a third ethernet cable connected, this will prevent you from using IPMI.  The most likely problem here is that the IPMI controller uses it's own MAC address to communicate with the outside world.  This is probably confusing the switch and bonding setup.